# How to achieve the outer div layout which have many inner div?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css

All the inner widgets are rendering with ng-repeat of angularjs. So number of widgets are dynamic and size of widgets are dynamic.

I want to achieve the below layout for my dashboard

[image]

But I am always getting the below layout

[image]

Is it possible to design dynamic layout like the image 1 layout using html,css and javascript?

I am sharing jsfiddle link: 
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yrxmvjt1/9/)

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="TodoCtrl" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
     <div class="" ng-repeat="widget in widgetList" ng-class="widget.class" draggable="true">{{widget.name}}</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Please help regarding this issue.

Comment: Try [Angular Matirial - Grid List](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/gridList)

Comment: That approach gets little messy if done via CSS and also has browser limitations. For best outcome, use Javascript plugins for Masonry layout.
[Masonry JS](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or [isotope js](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)

Comment: All these library gives suggestion of vertical scrollbar but I need it horizontal scrollbar.